# Группировка разрядов наоборот

Tags: javascript

Моя JavaScript функция принимает число `10000000.0000001` и должна вернуть такую строку `'10,00,00,00.000,000,1'`

Comment: А попытки решить были?

Comment: Да) const format = (num) => { const result = num.toString().split(".")} и дальше к сожалению все(

Answer (score 2):

Примитивное решение:

```js
let str = '10000000.0000001';
let parts = str.split('.');

let leftSide = parts[0].match(/.{1,2}/g).join(',');
let rigtSide = parts[1].match(/.{1,3}/g).join(',');

let result = `${leftSide}.${rigtSide}`;

console.log(result);
```

Тут мы делим число на 2 части по символу **точка**, потом левую часть разделяем по 2 символа `{1,2}`, а правую по три `{1,3}`. `.join(',')` - соединяет получившийся массив в строку с разделителем **запятая**.

Comment: Заметил, что минусы ставят за предоставление решений без попыток автора решить задачу. На самом деле - верно, но в свое оправдание скажу, что решать подобные задачки тоже интересно.

Comment: Привет, спасибо большое! Теперь буду знать что нужно свои попытки тоже предоставлять, решение крутое, супер

Comment: @Sergey в мое решение надо добавить проверки на наличие обоих частей (разделение по точке), так что дальше совершенствуй это дело.

Comment: Ну вот, решение неверное у тебя, а минус поставили мне :(

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин Сорян,  но я уверен что в любом случае помощь это круто, все вернется)

Comment: @Qwertiy почему решение не верное? Я указал, что решение примитивное на основе черного ящика. Тут не понятно, что надо делать с числами, которые не по формату идут, а додумать за автора не хочется

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин, ну логично по 2 разряда от точки, а не от начала. Если один нолик убрать, то у тебя получится `10,00,00,0.000,000,1`.

Comment: @Qwertiy возможно - да. Ну тогда просто надо reverse сделать и потом обратно)

Answer (score 1):

Могу сделать одной регуляркой (впрочем, за квадрат):

```js
function format(x) {
  return (x + "").replace(/(?!^)(?<!\..*)(?=(\d\d)+(\.|$))|(?!$)(?<=\.(\d\d\d)+)/g, ",")
}

console.log(format(10000000.0000001))
console.log(format(1000000.000001))
console.log(format(12.125))
console.log(format(12.5))
console.log(format(1.5))
console.log(format(1.1))
console.log(format(1.12))
console.log(format(1.123))
console.log(format(1.1234))
console.log(format(1.12345))
console.log(format(1.123456))
console.log(format(1.1234567))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Вставляем запятые в позиции:

- ИЛИ

  - И

    - не начало строки `(?!^)`
    - не после точки `(?<!\..*)`
    - от позиции до точки или конца строки чётное количество цифр `(?=(\d\d)+(\.|$))`
  - И

    - не конец строки `(?!$)`
    - от точки до позиции количество цифр кратно трём `(?<=\.(\d\d\d)+)`

Comment: Автор - новичок. Можешь объяснить тогда регулярное выражение по частям?

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин, готово. Ещё и баг обнаружил и поправил.